# Bitwise operations on negative numbers

Tags: c

I was reading a book on C, where in some section it says: " The bitwise operations are typically used with unsigned types.".

Question: why?

Comment: `unsigned` != negative.

Comment: @maroun maroun: did I say what you wrote?

Comment: The behaviour of the left shift operator on negative values of signed integers is undefined. The right one is implementation-defined.

Comment: @maroun maroun: I've read it couple of times, but don't find your comment _appropriate_

Comment: @dmcr_code You are right, my fault. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @maroun maroun: it's fine ....

Answer (score 5):

Simply because it is not immediately clear what bit operations on the sign bit of a signed number should mean.

- Unsigned types have no special bits, everything works straight
  forward.
- Signed types have a special sign bit and can interpret that with
  three different encodings to represent negative values (ones and two's complement or sign and magnitude).

Comment: Can you please give the encodings too?

Comment: one's complement, two's complement (the most usual one), and ... (please someone other add it, I don't know it by heart...)

Comment: Found it from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations): _The four best-known methods of extending the binary numeral system to represent signed numbers are: sign-and-magnitude, ones' complement, two's complement, and excess-K._ The last one is usually called biased numbers.

Comment: @legends2k, but only three of them are allowed in C.

Comment: Aah, this is why I asked (to know these little tidbits of information), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned operands do not have any special bits for sign representation.

For signed operands, the special bit for sign representation may interrupt operations which we want to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operations are typically used with unsigned types or signed types with non-negative values.

The C Standard supports 3 different representations for negative values: applying bitwise operators on such values has at best an implementation defined behavior.

For example `-1` is represented:

- as `|1000|0000|0000|0001|` on a 16-bit system with sign magnitude.
- as `|1111|1111|1111|1110|` on a 16-bit system with one's complement.
- and more commonly as `|1111|1111|1111|1111|` on a 16-bit system with two's complement.

As a consequence, `-1 & 3` can have 3 different values:

- `1` on sign-magnitude systems,
- `2` on one's complement systems,
- `3` on two's complement systems,

Other operations may behave in even more unexpected ways on negative numbers, such as `<<` and `>>`, especially on the [DS9K](http://www.worldwizzy.com/library/DeathStation_9000).

Conversely, the bitwise operations are fully defined on unsigned types, which are mandated to have binary representation (with some restrictions on the right operand of shift operators).

Answer (score 0):

From the programming languages' point of view the unsigned does not mean, that it cannot be negative. It means, that the first bit of the number is not used for determining if the value is negative or positive.

So, for an  8 bit value the bitwise operators consider all the 8 bits, thus working on the range 0..255 (while the mathematical operators can consider the first bit as being the signedness indicator, thus working on a range of -128 to +127).